# Is it true that ${\mathbb P}^1_{(1,2)} \cong {\mathbb P}^1$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

In a class on Algebraic geometry, we learnt the following - ${\mathbb P}^1_{(1,2)} \cong {\mathbb P}^1$ over the field ${\mathbb C}$. I'm not sure I followed the entire argument exactly. I'll reproduce my version of the argument against it. I hope a mistake can be pointed out.

${\mathbb P}^1$ is defined by two lines ${\mathbb A}^1_{\mathbb C}$ (parameterized by $s$ and $t$ respectively) with the transition function $s = \frac{1}{t}$.

Let us look at ${\mathbb P}^1_{(1,2)}$. A point can be described in projective coordinates $[x_0 : x_1 ] = [ \lambda x_0 ; \lambda^2 x_1 ] $. In the patch $U_0$ defined by $x_0 \neq 0$, we can describe a point here by $[1 ; s = \frac{x_1}{x_0^2} ] $. $s$ is unrestricted and therefore this patch is identical to ${\mathbb A}_{\mathbb C}^1$.

In the patch $U_1$ defined by $x_1 \neq 0$, we now choose $\lambda$ so that $x_1 = 1$. However, we note that one can make two choices here $\lambda = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_1}}$. Thus, the same point in this patch has two possible coordinates $[t = \frac{x_0}{\sqrt{x_1}};1]$ or $[-t;1]$. In this patch $t$ is unrestricted except that $t$ and $-t$ correspond to the same point. This patch is therefore identical to ${\mathbb A}^1_{\mathbb C}  / {\mathbb Z}_2$.

Here's where I have an issue now. Clearly the patches are different. How can ${\mathbb P}^1_{(1,2)} \cong {\mathbb P}^1$??? Unless....

> Is ${\mathbb A}^1_{\mathbb C}  / {\mathbb Z}_2 \cong {\mathbb A}^1_{\mathbb C}$?? If it is true, how should I then proceed with my argument to prove ${\mathbb P}^1_{(1,2)} \cong {\mathbb P}^1$?

Anyway, this was my argument. Let me also try and reproduce the argument presented by the professor as I understand it. I hope I can get a clearer explanation.

According my professor - $\frac{x_0}{\sqrt{x_1}}$ is clearly not a good coordinate on this patch since it is not single valued. We can therefore define a single-valued coordinate $t = \frac{x_0^2}{x_1}$. Now, since $t$ is unrestricted, this patch is identical to ${\mathbb A}^1_{\mathbb C}$. Further, we note that the transition functions are also the same as that of ${\mathbb P}^1$. Hence, ${\mathbb P}^1_{(1,2)} \cong {\mathbb P}^1$!

In a similar discussion, we went on to analyze ${\mathbb P}^2_{(1,1,2)}$. A similar situation arose here, but in this case, the professor said that the patch $U_2$ (where $x_2 \neq 0$ is identical to ${\mathbb A}^2_{\mathbb C}/{\mathbb Z}_2$ and therefore has an orbifold singularity. I don't understand how this space is singular if the one discussed above is not.

Thank you.

PS - I'm a student of physics and am not well-versed in math jargon. So any clarification of math words that you used would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is $P_{(1,2)}$?  Weighted projective space?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the confusion. The text of the question clarified that I think.

Comment: What is $P^1_{(1,1,2)}$?  If I understand correctly you are defining $\mathbb{P}^1$ as the quotient of $\mathbb{A}^2 - 0$ with a $\mathbb{G}_m$ (i.e. $\mathbb{C}^*$) action with certain weights, but there are only two dimensions to put weights on, unless I am confused.

Comment: Sorry. That should be a 2 in the superscript. Fixed.

Comment: Maybe it's a stupid comment, but I have a doubt about your isomorphism... and from what I've learned $\mathbb P^1 \simeq \mathbb P_{(1,1)}^1$, if I've understood your notation right ; in other words, in my second space $[x_0  : x_1] = [\lambda x_0 : \lambda x_1]$. Are you really saying it's still true if I replace the second $\lambda$ by $\lambda^2$? I've never heard of this result.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva - That is what I was told in class. Maybe there is a caveat to the statement that I'm missing. Is there any situation where the two spaces can be shown to be the same?

Comment: Take coordinates $s, t$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$.  The idea is that you are trying to parameterize orbits in $\mathbb{C}^2 - 0$: an orbit is $(\lambda s_0, \lambda^2 t_0)$ as $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}^*$.  If $s_0 \ne 0$ then this locus is the same locus as $(\lambda, \lambda^2 (t_0/s_0^2))$.  If $t_0 \ne 0$ then this is the same locus as $(\pm \lambda (s_0/\sqrt{t_0}), \lambda^2)$.  The square roots are awkward, but the equation that cuts out this second locus is still $s^2/t = s_0^2/t_0$, so that's what you want as an affine coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

Your space $\mathbb{P}^n_{(a_0, \ldots, a_n)}$ is the quotient of $\mathbb{A}^{n+1} - 0$ (not an affine space, since its global functions are teh same as $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$) by a $\mathbb{G}_m$ action with weights $a_1, \ldots, a_n$.  Say $\mathbb{A}^{n+1} = k[x_0, \ldots, x_n]$.  The $\mathbb{G}_m$ stable open affines are still given by $x_i \ne 0$.  So you can do everything explicitly.  Note that taking the quotient corresponds to taking invariants on local affines in the rings, and invariants for a $\mathbb{G}_m$ action are the degree 0 pieces (this is an exercise: that a $\mathbb{G}_m$-action on a space is the same as a $\mathbb{Z}$-grading on its ring of functions, and that the invariants are the degree 0 part of the grading).

So, for $\mathbb{P}^1_{(1, 2)}$, one has $k[x,y]$ where $x,y$ have weights $1,2$.  When $x \ne 0$ one has $k[y/x^2]$ as the degree zero (i.e. invariant) sections.  When $y \ne 0$ one has $k[x^2/y]$.  These generators are reciprocals of each other, so it's the same as in $\mathbb{P}^1$: two copies of $\mathbb{A}^1$ glued in the same way.

For $\mathbb{P}^2_{(1,1,2)}$ one has $k[x,y,z]$ with weights $1,1,2$.  The open affines are $k[y/x, z/x^2]$, $k[x/y, z/y^2]$ and $k[x^2/z, y^2/z, xy/z^2]$.  Notice that the while the first two rings are just $\mathbb{A}^2$, the generators for the last ring satisfy a relation: that is
$$(x^2/z) (y^2/z) = (xy/z)^2$$
so it's isomorphic to the ring
$$k[A,B,C]/AB - C^2$$
which has a type $A_1$/ordinary double point/rational surface singularity, i.e. obtained from quotienting $\mathbb{A}^2$ by $\mathbb{Z}/2$.

Edit: Also, $\mathbb{A}^1/(\mathbb{Z}/2) = \mathbb{A}^1$.  To see this, take invariants: $\mathbb{Z}/2$ sends $x \mapsto -x$ in $k[x]$ and the invariant ring is $k[x^2]$ which is still a polynomial ring on one generator.  However, $\mathbb{A}^2/(\mathbb{Z}/2)$ where $x \mapsto -x$ and $y \mapsto -y$ (think of $\mathbb{Z}/2$ as the central subgroup of $SL_2$ acting on $\mathbb{A}^2$) has invariant ring $k[x^2, xy, y^2] = k[A,B,C]/AC-B^2$, which is the same ring as above, and singular.

Comment: I'll need some time to understand all of that. Thanks!

Comment: A comment: the vague reason that the invariant ring corresponds to the quotient is that the quotient space is the space of orbits, and the invariant functions are the only ones which have any chance of being defined on such a space.  However it's not clear that every orbit can be separated from another by an invariant function (for example, if we take $\mathbb{A}^n$ and the quotient by $\mathbb{G}_m$ one has only the constant functions as invariants).  In our case here, by taking $\mathbb{A}^n - 0$, the action is locally free, so things work out nicely.  In more general situations you need GIT